# Existence of maps on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ satisfying $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many maps $\phi : \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \to  \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} $ are there with the property that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} $?

My Attempt is
$$\phi(0)+\phi(m)=\phi(0) \implies \phi(m)=0\quad \text{ for all } m \in  \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$$

Hence there is only one such map.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: I would also mention that conversely $\phi(m) \equiv 0$ is indeed a solution (what's written so far technically only proves there is *at most* one such map).

Answer (score 1):

You've got the correct conclusion, but it could use a tiny bit more justification. I'd express it as $$\varphi(0)+\varphi(m)=\varphi(0m)=\varphi(0),$$ just to make it perfectly clear.